# Converting remote relative paths to absolute paths

Tags: php, html, parsing

I tried looking for a similar question, but was unable to.

I'm looking for push in the right direction. What I'm currently doing is 
gathering a list of all href values of a remote site, now since some of them can be 
relative paths, I need a function that builds an absolute path.

Since I have the domain name (by following the last url cUrl used):

```
$base_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```

Now lets say $base_url value is: http://www.example.com/home/index.html
and href value I'm currently reading is: /styles/ie.css

I need to turn the value of $base_url to http://www.example.com/styles/ie.css
but I need that function to be dynamic as much as possible. Take a look at the
possible scenarios (probably a not all):

```
1 = base url
2 = relative path
------------------------------------------------
1 http://www.example.com/
2 java/popups.js

1 + 2 = http://www.example.com/java/popups.js
------------------------------------------------
1 http://www.example.com
2 java/popups.js

1 + / + 2 = http://www.example.com/java/popups.js
------------------------------------------------
1 http://www.example.com/mysite/
2 ../java/popups.js 

1 - / + (2 - ..) = http://www.example.com/java/popups.js
------------------------------------------------

1 http://www.example.com/rsc/css/intlhplib-min.css
2 ../images/sunflower.png

1 - /css/intlhplib-min.css + (2 - ..) = http://www.example.com/rsc/images/sunflower.png
```

Comment: Where are you getting the href value?

Comment: I'm getting the entire html then parsing it. I end up with an array of values retrieved from any href attribute on it.

Comment: @bozdoz I'm testing it as we speak, will let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing my own function, after a push in the right direction from @bozdoz.

The function takes two arguments, first one is $resource, which is the relative file path.
And the second one is is the base url (which will be used to construct an absolute url).

This was design for my project purposes, I'm not sure it will fit anyone who is looking
for a similar solution. Feel free to use it, and provide any efficiency improvements.

**Updated version** Thanks to [Tim Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142162/tim-cooper)

```
function rel2abs_v2($resource, $base_url) 
{
$base_url = parse_url($base_url);

if(substr($resource, 0, 4) !== "http" && substr($resource, 0, 5) !== "https") // if no http/https is present, then {$resource} is a relative path.
{
# There is a "../" in the string
if (strpos($resource, "../") !== false)
{
$dir_count = substr_count($resource, "../");

$path_array = explode("/", $base_url["path"]);
$path_count = count($path_array); // 4
$path_index = ($path_count - $dir_count) - 2;

$resource = trim(str_replace("../", "", $resource));

if($path_index > 0) { $fs = "/"; }

if($dir_count > 0)
{
$base_url_path = implode("/", array_slice($path_array, $dir_count, $path_index - $dir_count + 1));
return $base_url['scheme'] . '://' . $base_url['host'] . $fs . $base_url_path ."/". $resource;
}
}

# Latest addition - remove if unexplained behaviour is in place.
if(starts_with($resource, "//"))
{
return trim(str_replace("//", "", $resource));      
}

if (starts_with($resource, "/"))
{
return $base_url["scheme"] . "://" . $base_url["host"] . $resource;
}
else
{
$path_array = explode("/", $base_url["path"]);

end($path_array);
$last_id = key($path_array);

return $base_url["scheme"] . "://" . $base_url["host"] . "/" . $path_array[--$last_id] . "/" . $resource;
}

}
else
{
return $resource;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to use regular expressions on the href path to make sure that it is consistent.  You can also get an accurate base url from [parse_url](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)():

```
<?php
$href = '../images/sunflower.png';
$href = preg_replace('~^\.{0,2}\/~', '', $href);
?>
```

Here we strip the periods and the slashes from the beginning of the string.  And then prepend the base url:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com/home/index.html';
$url = parse_url($url);

$abspath = $url['scheme'] . '://' . $url['host'] . '/' . $href;

echo $abspath;
?>
```

Should output what you want: `http://www.example.com/images/sunflower.png`

### UPDATE

If you want the first directory from the base url, then use explode on the parsed url's path key:

```
$first_directory = '';
if (isset($url['path'])) {
    $patharray = explode('/', $url['path']);
    if (count($patharray)>2){
        $first_directory = explode('/', $url['path'])[1] . '/';
    }
}
```

And add that to the output variable:

```
$abspath = $url['scheme'] . '://' . $url['host'] . '/' . $first_directory . $href;
```

### Another Update

To find how the href values relate to the base url, you can search for the occurence of `../` or `/` at the beginning of the href value, and then adjust your absolute url accordingly.  This should help you figure out what the scenarios are:

```
<?php
$href = '../../images/sunflower.png';
preg_match('~^(\.{0,2}\/)+~', $href, $matches); //preg_match to check if it exists
if (substr_count($matches[0], '../')){ // substr_count to count number of '../'
    echo 'Go up ' . substr_count($matches[0], '../') . ' directories';
}
else if (substr_count($matches[0], '/')){
    echo 'Root directory';
}
else {
    echo 'Current directory';
}
?>
```

Check the demo on [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/pnZ5KH).

Comment: That wont cover most of the possible outcomes. if the href value is images/sunflower.png and the url is http://www.example.com/home/index.html the absolute path should be http://www.example.com/home/images/sunflower.png

Comment: So you always want the first directory from your URL variable?  Your question did not make that clear.

Comment: Well not exactly. I need a way to compute the relative path in various scenarios. I can see the url["path"] holds that directories structure but I'm having problems with figuring the way to account for all possible outcomes. if no "/" is present at the beginning of the href value, that means its relative to the current working directory, But if there is a "/" character that means it should go up a directory. te same applies later on, when I'll try to parse relative css image paths where a css file can be places under "home/resources/styles.css" and it will have url("../../images").

Comment: @elad.chen I see what you mean.  You'll have to do a regex match and a count on the href, checking for `\.{0,2}\/`

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Check the update.  That should help you compute the relative path.