# read array from 1 to 3 indexes

Tags: php, arrays

Following on my project I discovered I'm doing something wrong.

[converting-remote-relative-paths-to-absolute-paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127738/converting-remote-relative-paths-to-absolute-paths/17127829)

The question: in my rel2abs function I have the following array:

> Array ( [0] => [1] => a [2] => 1371147400 [3] => t1 [4] => css [5] => t1_core_logged_out.bundle.css )

I'm able to compute the index of which I should start reading from, but I also need the preceding values. the path I'm building should be read from index number 3, but the string I'm building should be the values between 1 and 3; which would output:

> a/1371147400/t1

What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) and [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice):

```
$start = 1;
$end = 3;
$str = implode("/", array_slice($arr, $start, $end - $start + 1));
```

Comment: That is precisely what I was looking for! thanks. What do you think of the function rel2abs ? penny for your thoughts :)